# Order By desc for 3 types of logged in users

Tags: sql-server, session, sql-order-by

I keep users session for 2 hours for statistics reasons, but 'real' user are one which did some action in the past half an hour.
I need to sort the users by their actions:

1. First will be the real users,
2. Second will be the users in the statistics state (hence didn't make
   an action for more than half an hour, but their session is less than
   2 hours),
3. and last are all the rest (their statistics state is over).

**I'm using 2 columns: *IsLogin (bit)* and *LastAction (DateTime)* columns.**
My logic is that sorting first by bit for logged in users and then sort by the timespan will be suffice.

I'm talking of around 200,000 users, 50% are online.
Every user can do that search so I need to do the search as quickly as possible.
Notice that when user is logging in - he/she is ordered first until the next one is logging in, then he/she become second and so on.
I'm using scrolling pagination of 20 per page (scrolling down retrieves the next 20).
The table has 23 columns.

- Am I using the right columns?
- Need I do something else?
- Does selection by bit column and then order by timespan will be
  faster than just ask if timespan is less than 30 minutes from now and
  then order by?

Comment: The question is still not completely clear. Which is the exact search that can do every user? Is that search "look for all the 200.000 users and return them orderd by the criterions 1,2,3, in batches of 20"? Does it make sense? Is anybody going to paginate 10.000 times to get all the results? When the user scrolls down to get 20 more, does he get the 40 first or the next 20? Does he get the current next 20 or those who were the next 20 when he asked the list for the first time? Please, complete your desing or make your question more clear. It still makes no sense. Thus, I've removed my answer.

Comment: @JotaBe - I can't understand what troubles you. You've done such a search everywhere on the web, starting with google images, through facebook, ending with thousands websites like what I'm describing.
Of course I'm retrieving only the next 20 results and add them right after the last 20 results.
My only question was how to order the results with my described criterias. What would be the most effective way.

Comment: I'm not trying to disturb you. You can improve performance when it's clear what has to be done. There are several important details, for example, 1st: if you always return first the real users and the user s for the last 2 hours, is it really possible that someone navigates further than this two types of users? Perhaps you can filter the rest out; 2nd: the list changes continuously so if a user gets the 20 first, and later the 21 to 40, as the second query is executed later is possible that the 20th user in the first query has gone donw to 23th in the second, so it's shown twice. Right?

Comment: The number of columns (and specially its size) is an important design detail, because it can make sense to crea an index or not depending on it. It's also possible to maintain an auxiliary table ordered by your criteria, which only holds the people in the 1st, or the 1st and second groups, and use it to make the queries, and update it whenever a new user logs in. There are many factors to give an uninformed, but designed answer.